# How to store a image and rename that image at the same time while storing?

Tags: java, image, swing, file, jfilechooser

Want to create a `JFileChooser` and a `JTextField`Then browse an image from any folder. Path is given, so it will rename the image and the image name would be the `jtextfield.getText();` then store in my specified path. 
I know it's hard to implement. I did some part.

`JFileChooser` and `jtextfield` is created. Image is getting stored in my specified path. But it's not renaming the image. (Rename image should be the jtextfield.jpg)

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.io.File;

public class ImgClass {

    public ImgClass() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Save Image");

                    final JTextField username = new JTextField();
            username.setBounds(105, 102, 192, 20);
            frame.add(username);
            username.setColumns(10);

        JButton saveImage = new JButton("Browse");
        saveImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "JPG, GIF, and PNG Images", "jpg", "gif", "png");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("You choose to open this file: "
                            + file.getName());
                    BufferedImage image;
                    try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(file);
                       ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("D:\\Img\\" + username.getText()+".jpg"));
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ImgClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }              
                }
            }
        });



        frame.add(saveImage);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ImgClass saveImageFile = new ImgClass();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [tag:java-ee] tag removed.

Comment: You should be using `showSaveDialog` for saving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the **same** file name when writing the file. Consider getting the text from the JTextField and using it.

```
String newName = username.getText();

// no not this!
// File newFile = new File("D:\\Img\\" + file.getName()));

// but this!
file newFile = new File("D:\\Img\\" + newName));
// write with newFile
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Good approach. But the problem is : If I write ' abc' in jtextfield then image will file format is storing wrong. If I write abc.jpg in jtextfield then it works fine. Please suggest me with any modification.

I challenge you to write a small bit of code that **checks** the String (named newName above) to see if it ends in `".jpg"` or something similar such as `".JPG"` and if not, then provide the String with such an ending. I have confidence that you can solve this. ;)

Comment: Good approach. But the problem is : If I write ' abc' in jtextfield then image will file format is storing wrong. 
If I write abc.jpg in jtextfield then it works fine. 
Please suggest me with any modification.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee: easy to fix, and I challenge you to do so. Please see edit above.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee: if you get stuck in this attempt, please show what you've done as an edit to your question, and then post a comment to me down here. Myself, I'd use the String method `.endsWith(...)`.

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee: or you could just [look it up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10471512/522444)

Comment: You are too good. 
My edited part :

ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",new File("D:\\Img\\" + username.getText()+".jpg"));

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee The extension is irrelevant, what you pass to ImageIO will determine the format that is actually used

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Then what should I do . Help me please

Comment: @IndranilBanerjee: re `"what should I do"` -- better define your current problem if you're still having them.

Comment: @  Hovercraft Full Of Eels : Thanks a lot. You helped me a lot to solve my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following code:

```
 String fileName = user.getId()+"."+file.getOriginalFilename()
            .substring(
                    file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

    System.out.println("User id : "+user.getId());
    user.setImage(FOLDER_PATH+fileName);

    file.transferTo(new File(FOLDER_PATH+fileName));
```